# cannot separate .txt file by commas using pd.read_fwf()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to read the following .txt file and convert it to a pandas dataFrame object. But I cannot separate the columns. I have tried `pd.read_fwf('housing.txt',delimiters=',')`. It didn't work.

```
df = pd.read_fwf('housing.txt',delimiter = ',',names=['a','b','c'])
```

The output:

```
a   b   c
0   2104,3,399900   NaN NaN
1   1600,3,329900   NaN NaN
2   2400,3,369000   NaN NaN
3   1416,2,232000   NaN NaN
4   3000,4,539900   NaN NaN
5   1985,4,299900   NaN NaN
6   1534,3,314900   NaN NaN
```

Here is the `housing.txt` file

```
2104,3,399900
1600,3,329900
2400,3,369000
1416,2,232000
3000,4,539900
1985,4,299900
1534,3,314900
1427,3,198999
1380,3,212000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read_csv`, as this is a comma-separated values (CSV) file:

```
df = pd.read_csv("housing.txt", names=['a','b','c'])
```